# Jenkins TestComplete get test Execution Id from Jira

Tags: jenkins, jira, testcomplete

I need to integrate **TestComplete** and **Jira** to **Jenkins**. My requirement is to get test `Execution Id` from **Jira** and pass that execution Id to **TestComplete** through **Jenkins**. Is there any way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

TestComplete and Jenkins already have integration which could be found [Here](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/working-with/integration/jenkins/index.html)

As for grabbing the execution ID... TestComplete has an operation called [Set-Variable Value](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/keyword-testing/reference/statements/set-variable-value.html).  This allows you to store any value from the machine as a variable to use later.  One of my favorite features in TC.  This should give exactly what you need.  Just be aware that you could also [Log a message](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/keyword-testing/reference/logging/message.html) and customize the message with any stored values as well

Comment: Execution Id's are stored in Jira, my requirement is to capture those execution id's from jira and provide as dropdown in jenkins. Is it possible or is there any work around for that requirement

Comment: TC can store values, and there are integrations between all 3 tools, how you decide to setup the flow between tools and the data is entirely up to you.